# Convergence of a series of the product of two functions when one of them is shifted by one

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, pointwise-convergence, smooth-functions

Suppose $f(x)$ is a smooth function and $g_n(x)$ is a sequence of functions such that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^{(n)}(x) g_n(x)
$$
converges for $x \in [a,b]$, where $f^{(n)}(x)$ denotes the $n$-th derivative of $f(x)$.
Can we make any conclusions about the convergence of the "shifted" series

\begin{equation} \label{1}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^{(n+1)}(x) g_n(x),
\end{equation}
or at least determine if $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f^{(n+1)}(x) g_n(x) = 0, \ \forall \, x \in [a,b]$?

If not, what additional conditions would I need to ensure either the convergence of the shifted series or of the shifted limit?  Thank you.

Comment: In general this won't be true; for example, take $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g_n(x)=0$ when $n$ is odd while $g_n(x){{}={}}$(some small nonnegative function) when $n$ is even.

Comment: Your example doesn't meet the condition that $\sum f^{(n)}(x) g_n(x)$ converges. If we let $g(x)$ be the small nonnegative function when $n$ is even, we would get the following partial sums: $S_1(x) = 0, \ S_2(x) = -\sin (x) g(x), \ S_3(x) = -\sin (x) g(x), \ S_4(x) = 0, \ S_5(x) = 0$, etc. which doesn't converge.

Comment: Some small nonnegative function depending on $n$....